# How to get empty document's ID in FirebaseFirestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get collection's all documents. However all of the documents in that collection do not have any fields, but they continue with subcollections like so:

*(collection 'messages') -> (documents of senders' ID) -> (collection 'receivers' -> (documents of receivers' ID) -> (collection 'messages') -> (documents for messages with fields).*

**I want to get all of the receivers for specific sender.**

I was considering two things:

1. Find the way to get empty document's ID
2. Or add the ID to the document as a field. However, when I add receiver's ID I do not know how to continue to add collection 'messages' and messages. Is there any way for this (second) solution to add document's ID and then CONTINUE adding collection, instead of starting all over again calling database and adding collection with messages. I think this is inefficient.

Working with Java and Android.